# Cassandra: CorruptSSTableException when opening Descriptor instance

Tags: java, cassandra

I'm trying to read data from SSTable files in a directory using Java. Here's what I have now:

```java
Descriptor descriptor = new Descriptor("md", new File("path-to-directory"), "test", "people", 1, SSTableFormat.Type.BIG);
SSTableReader reader = SSTableReader.open(descriptor); // (1)
```

`CorruptSSTableException` was thrown when (1) is executed, caused by `ExceptionInitializerError`, which was caused by `NullPointerException`. 
And it says file "md-1-big-Statistics.db" is corrupted.

But when I used the command line tool `sstabledump`, everything works fine so I think the file "md-1-big-Statistics.db" should not be corrupted. So my questions are:

(1) How to deal with this Exception?
or
(2) Is there another way to read SSTables using Java?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

**[Appendix]**

1. File folder structure:
   The directory is `/test/people`, where "test" is keyspace, and "people" is cfname. In the directory there are the following files:

   - md-1-big-CompressionInfo.db
   - md-1-big-Data.db
   - md-1-big-Digest.crc32
   - md-1-big-Filter.db
   - md-1-big-Index.db
   - md-1-big-Statistics.db
   - md-1-big-Summary.db
   - md-1-big-TOC.txt

Comment: what version of cassandra are you using in your classpath?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I'm using 3.11.4